# removeEventListner() does not take affect

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to make a card game. In my game user obligated to choose one of cards(I add `EventListeners` to every card, which is `<img>` in my HTML) and after picking he shouldn't be allow click on any other card(I have to remove all `EventListeners`).

For some reasons this code doesn't remove `EventListeners` and I am still able to perform action. I want to avoid creating separate function outside `addEventListener()`.

```
MessageHandler.prototype.give_card_to_next_player = function (evt) {
    let myCardBox = document.getElementById("my-hand").childNodes;
    for (card of myCardBox){
        card.addEventListener("click", function _listener(choosen_card) {
            message_handler.sendMessage({
                "type": "give_away_card",
                "choosen_card": [...myCardBox].indexOf(choosen_card.target),
                "for_player": evt.nextPlayer
            });

            choosen_card.target.remove();
            for (card of myCardBox){
                card.removeEventListener("click", _listener);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: What sort of elements are the children of the `#my-hand`? `<div>`s? Do they have a class name or something?

Comment: @Snow Only `<img>`, they don't have a class name for now

Comment: That's fine, makes things even easier. If they could have had children of their own, things would've been a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's a click, the `_listener` that you remove is the `_listener` function defined *in that loop*:

```
for (card of myCardBox){
    card.addEventListener("click", function _listener(choosen_card) {
```

Every iteration, you define a *new* `_listener` function. So when you do

```
card.removeEventListener("click", _listener);
```

inside the loop, you are referencing the `_listener` for that iteration only - for that `card` only. So, only the listener for that one card gets removed - the other cards have a listener which is a *different* function reference.

For the same reason, the functions in the below snippet are not `===`.

```js
const fns = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  fns.push(function foo(){});
}
console.log(fns[0] === fns[1]);
```

`removeEventListener` will only remove a function which is `===` to one which was passed to `addEventListener` earlier.

How about using event delegation instead? Add only one listener to the container, and remove it whenever a click goes through.

```
MessageHandler.prototype.give_card_to_next_player = function (evt) {
  const hand = document.getElementById("my-hand");
  const cards = [...hand.children];
  hand.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    // if click was on the container but not on any cards, don't do anything
    if (target === hand) return;

    // Remove event listener
    hand.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);

    // Calculate index, send message
    const index = cards.indexOf(target);
    message_handler.sendMessage({
      "type": "give_away_card",
      "choosen_card": index,
      "for_player": evt.nextPlayer
    });
  });
};
```